# Avoid repetition between Django ModelForm and Django Model

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, dry

I'm interested is there a way to avoid repetition between Django ModelForm and Django Model.
E.g. I have this simplest Model:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
```

and corresponding ModelForm to it

```
class CategoryForm(forms.ModelForm):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    class Meta:
        model = Category
        fields = ('name',)
```

As we can see there is repetition between these entities. This code

```
max_length=128
```

- does it violate "Don't repeat yourself" principle?
And if it violates, how can we avoid this duplication of code?

Comment: The second class is inherited from `Model` instead of `ModelForm`, is that a typo? Alsoyou dont have to define the fields in `ModelForm` explicitly at all.

Comment: Yes, it's a typo.I fixed it.Excuse me.Now it should be OK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out in the other answer, you don't need to re declare the fields in the ModelForm. You only need to list them out in the fields attribute of the class Meta. If you feel that is not DRY enough. You can use `__all__`

> Set the fields attribute to the special value '**all**' to indicate
>   that all fields in the model should be used. For example:

Ref: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/modelforms/

Answer (score 1):

But you do not have to specify `name` field in Form one more time in your case.

You are using ModelForm, so in Meta just define model, which is referred to this Form and fields, that should be used in form. Django will fetch widgets and build form for you.

So that's enough

```
class CategoryForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Category
        fields = ('name',)
```

Answer (score 0):

--Model

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
```

-Form

```
class CategoryForm(forms.ModelForm):
  class Meta:
    model = Category
    fields = ('name',)
```

-View

```
class CategoryView(request):
    form = CategoryForm()
    if request.method == "POST":
        #code..
        return render(request,'htmlpage.html',{Variables: Variables})
    else: 
        return render(request, "htmlpage.html",{'form':form})
```

Created 'form', view page loads. Here the request from html page is queried with POST. If the post is not requested, the FORM template is sent to the html page.